# How do you pronounce Nekot (as in Nekot Cookies)?

Tags: pronunciation

Lance Crackers™ has a type of cookie called "Nekot" and we were having a discussion in our office about the correct way to pronounce it. We each say it in different ways: "Knee-cot", "Knee-coat", "Knee-co" and "Neck-it".

Which way is the correct way/is there a correct way?

Comment: The "correct" way to pronounce a name may be judged as either the way the bearer of the name (or intimates thereof) pronounces it, or how your peers pronounce it. This is especially the case with invented words like *Nekot*. Since their website provides no guidance, you'll need to find audio of someone from Lance pronouncing it, e.g. from a television ad or an investor call or a press conference.

Comment: Good idea for the ads, I'll try and search for those.

Comment: Also keep in mind that words are pronounced differently depending on one’s native accent’s phonological “rules”. These produce different phonetic allophones but everybody knows it’s the same word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook user to Lance Snacks (maker of Nekot)

> How do you pronounce "Nekot"?

Lance Snacks:

> It's pronounced "knee-cot".

This thrilling exchange can be found at

https://www.facebook.com/LanceSnacks/posts/781993908524510

Answer (score 0):

There's no obvious pronunciation for it from first principles.

- '-kot' is rare
- 'nek-' is rare
- it's hard to tell where the syllables split in 'nekot' (though 'nek-ot' is more plausible).

And because English is so idiosyncratic, at least for shorter words, you're sort of left with nothing. In this case, a pronunciation is usually mandated: if it is a foreign borrowing or a one-off neologism, then someone just makes something up.

The snack makers (Lance) said it's /'ni: kɑt/ or 'knee-cot'.

Most people don't bother pronouncing it, and just point: 'Which ones? Those."

Comment: This is the correct answer!!